# Subversion, download specific folder from repo

Tags: svn, merge

I was trying to merge a branch into trunk but wasn't successful maybe due to not having updated the trunk into branch before the merge.

So, now I want to restart the whole process. I've checked out a copy of the branchX but some files in a folder haven't changed after the checkout - they are the old files of the trunk.  There were some tree conflicts after the checkout so I've resolved them with `svn resolve --accept working files or directories`.

The problem is that some files haven't been downloaded. So I want to download the whole branch again as it is at the repo ignoring local structure.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not just use SVN 1.8+ without such merge-headache?

Comment: @LazyBadger: There isn't merging functionality at SVN 1.8+? Or they've done it better?

Comment: There **is** merge in SVN 1.8+. And yes, merging in 1.8 is a lot easier and simple

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the branch to a different local directory. This local directory can be empty, so after the checkout there will be locally only the files downloaded from the repository.

Comment: I wanted though checkout the branch to the current directory as it's where there is the Netbeans project files that where created with the project. Is there any way to do that? I simply downloaded the branch to another local dir and copied all the files from that dir to the current.

Comment: You could rename (using the operating system tool) the old directory and do a checkout to the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using google code? I have faced such problems many times.

I think the better way to do this is to make a checkout in a new local folder. This way you will have everything correct from your repo. Then go to your older local folder and take any files  that is not included in your new folder or change any files that are different. Then do a commit. This way you will avoid future problems again. Do not copy from the new directory to the old instead do the opposite (from the old to the new whatever is missing) and when everything is fine the go and delete the old folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Andreas, although I am using assembla! What I did to solve this, was deleting all files from my current folder, including the `.svn` and then checked out the branch I needed. Everything worked fine!